# Capture ctrl + I and ctrl + B in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Silverlight? When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> the *Organize Favourite* window pops up.